# Convert serial output to human readable string (x0c005021)

Tags: python, binary, hex, ascii

Working with a queing system (supplied by QMatic). We want to connect a serial cable into a Linux computer to detect changes, eg if a queing number is changed

Currently I'm using python that reads the serial port. When changing the number in QMatic, I get like this: b'\x0c005021\r' (8 bytes) ?
How do I convert this to human readable output? What IS x0c005021? Hex?

Answer (score 1):

It's a series of 8 bytes.  One way to look at it is like this in the interactive console:

```
>>> b = b'\x0c005021\r'
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> len(b)
8
>>> [i for i in b]
[12, 48, 48, 53, 48, 50, 49, 13]
```

So the first byte is 12, which is some kind of form feed character?  This is the "\x0c" at the start.  This is followed by the ascii codes for the characters 0, 0, 5, 0, 2, 1 (as you can already read in your sample), followed by byte 13, which is the `\r`.

So the readable bit is "005021" with control bytes before and after.